# Bigtable's (Golang) admin client is erroring with "A DropRowRange operation is already ongoing"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

When a user deletes a resource, I'd like to iterate through a few relevant rowRanges in Bigtable, and delete them. I have 3+ calls to `admin.DropRowRange(ctx, table, rowKeyPrefix)`. Some of the calls are applied to the same table; each call is applied to a different rowRange.

The majority of the time this has worked. However, now I've received an error "a DropRowRange operation is already ongoing."

I haven't found this error documented anywhere, and I haven't found anyone else report it.

Are there constraints for how frequently I can call the function? Are the constraints general or for a given table or for a given rowRange? Are there any recommended workarounds?

It feels like the error could be due to the same operation getting retried twice, and possibly the DropRowRange operation isn't idempotent. Is this it?

Comment: Hello Eric, can you check if you have any Bigtable quota exceeded on the IAM & Admin > Quotas >

Comment: @Jaroslav, thanks for the thought, but we are comfortably within our quotas

Comment: Are you getting any return code according to https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/status-codes#returned_codes ?

Comment: @Jaroslav, yes, the code is "UNAVAILABLE" and the description is "a DropRowRange operation is already ongoing."

Answer (score 0):

DropRowRange operation is used to permanently drop/delete a row range from a [specified table](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances.tables/dropRowRange). At the moment it is only allowed to call it once at a time which is also the case you're hitting.
We are however working on allowing this method to be called in parallel, but there is no ETA for this yet. You can follow this [public issue](http://%20https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154142297) to get updates about the progress.

Comment: Is it allowed to be called once at a time _per given row range_? Or is it allowed to be called once at a time _per table_? And, if the latter, is there any recommended workaround?

Comment: It is per table. I don't there is a workaround apart from controlling that you don't run two of these commands in parallel.